# dataflow HDF5 loading pipeline errors

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Any help will be greatly appreciated!!!

I an using dataflow to process H5 ([HDF5 format](https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/)) file.

For that, I have created a setup.py file that is based on [juliaset](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/5c74022da1bb8f8a822cf3c545f96f2903d175a4/sdks/python/apache_beam/examples/complete/juliaset/setup.py) example that was reference in one of the other tickets. my only change there is the list of packages to install:

```py
REQUIRED_PACKAGES = [
    'numpy',
    'h5py',
    'pandas',
    'tables',
    ]
```

The pipeline is the following:

```py
import numpy as np
import h5py
import pandas as pd
import argparse
import logging
import re
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.io import ReadFromText
from apache_beam.io import WriteToText
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import SetupOptions


class ReadGcsBlobs(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, element, *args, **kwargs):
        from apache_beam.io.gcp import gcsio
        gcs = gcsio.GcsIO()
        yield (element, gcs.open(element).read())

class H5Preprocess(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, element):
        logging.info('**********starting to read H5')
        h5py.File(element, 'r')
        logging.info('**********finished reading H5')
        expression = hdf['/data/']['expression']
        logging.info('**********finished reading the expression node')
        np_expression = expression[1:2,1:2]
        logging.info('**********subset the expression to numpy 2x2')
        yield (element, np_expression)

def run(argv=None):
    pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(argv)
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="read from h5 blog and write to file")
    #parser.add_argument('--input',help='Input for the pipeline', default='gs://archs4/human_matrix.h5')
    #parser.add_argument('--output',help='output for the pipeline',default='gs://archs4/output.txt')
    #known_args, pipeline_args = parser.parse_known_args(argv)
    logging.info('**********finish with the parser')

    # what does the args is relevant for? when the parameters are known_args.input and known_args.output
    #with beam.Pipeline(options=PipelineOptions(argv=pipeline_args)) as p:
    with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:
            (p 
                | 'Initialize' >> beam.Create(['gs://archs4/human_matrix.h5']) 
                | 'Read-blobs' >> beam.ParDo(ReadGcsBlobs()) 
                | 'pre-process' >> beam.ParDo(H5Preprocess()) 
                | 'write' >> beam.io.WriteToText('gs://archs4/outputData.txt')
            )
    p.run()       

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)
    run()
```

the execution command is the following:

```
python beam_try1.py --job-name beam-try1 --project orielresearch-188115 --runner DataflowRunner --setup_file ./setup.py --temp_location=gs://archs4/tmp --staging_location gs://archs4/staging
```

and the pipeline Error is the following:

```
(5a4c72cfc5507714): Workflow failed. Causes: (3bde8bf810c652b2): S04:Initialize/Read+Read-blobs+pre-process+write/Write/WriteImpl/WriteBundles/WriteBundles+write/Write/WriteImpl/Pair+write/Write/WriteImpl/WindowInto(WindowIntoFn)+write/Write/WriteImpl/GroupByKey/Reify+write/Write/WriteImpl/GroupByKey/Write failed., (7b4a7abb1a692d12): A work item was attempted 4 times without success. Each time the worker eventually lost contact with the service. The work item was attempted on: 
  beamapp-eila-0213182449-2-02131024-1621-harness-vf4f,
  beamapp-eila-0213182449-2-02131024-1621-harness-vf4f,
  beamapp-eila-0213182449-2-02131024-1621-harness-vf4f,
  beamapp-eila-0213182449-2-02131024-1621-harness-vf4f
```

Could you please advice what need to be fixed?

Thanks,
eilalan

Answer (score 0):

did you try to run a subset of the data in the local runner? That might give you more info on what's going wrong.

Comment: Yes. I have tried . I am running the code now on datalab. The CGS is opening the file and the h5py.File must have a full path name and not an object. I have decided to combine H5py and beam. first step will be to extract the data from the H5py to a numpy array or dataframe. the first step is working correctly. Will it be possible to pass the numpy array to Pipeline to create a PCollection or what will be the best way to write it to BigQuery or to GCS. The file is long and writing from datalab is not reliable and will take forever. Thanks, Eila

Comment: As far as I know you can't pass the numpy array to Pipeline as it is. According to this documentation (https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/pcollection#bounded-pcollections), BigQueryIO or DatastoreIO are valid Data sources to create bounded PCollection.